# Spectral decomposition to find $2^A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Find the spectral decomposition of $A$. This is $$A=VDV^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
My question how do I find $2^A$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Raise each eigenvalue to the power of 2. Think about this as $e^{\log(2)A}$ and the power series for $e$. (Requires some small amount of algebraic manipulation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a diagonalizable matrix $A=VDV^{-1}$:
$$f(A) = V\begin{bmatrix}f(d_1)&0 \\ 0&f(d_2)\end{bmatrix}V^{-1}$$
Hence
$$ 2^A = V\begin{bmatrix}2^1&0 \\ 0&2^5\end{bmatrix}V^{-1}$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Note that using that decomposition$$A^k=VD^kV^{-1}$$and $$2^A=\sum {A^n(\ln 2)^n\over n!}$$